# Combinatorical method proving Euler's theorem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, combinatorial-proofs

If this a duplicate question than I apologize.

How would you prove Euler's theorem using combinatorics? The theorem goes:

$x^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod n$ where $(x, n)=1$

I can only come up with proofs for this related to number theory. Any hints or advice?

Comment: It is important to specify that $(x,n)=1$.

Comment: Thank you, I edited that in

Comment: The only slightly combintorial proof I know is where you examine two different lists of congruence classes, count them, note they are equal, then prove the theorem.  Good enough?  (The best proof is via ring theory and the group of units, but that's not combinatorial.)

Comment: If you replace $\phi(n)$ by $\prod_{p^k \|n} \phi(p^k)$ then it is enough to show it for $n = p^k$ where it is slightly easier. See what you get when $n=p$ is prime

Comment: Do you believe in the freshman's dream mod $p$?  Because then there is a combinatorial proof (kinda) by the binomial theorem.

Comment: I'll give both of your suggestions a try. But @Randall I've never heard of the freshman's dream mod p before

Comment: Freshman's dream claims that $(a+b)^p = a^p + b^p \bmod p$.  You can prove it by expanding by the binomial theorem then examining the coefficients $\binom{p}{k} \bmod p$, which all die except for the first and last.

Comment: Wait, I'm out of line.  This only gets you Euler's Theorem in the case $n$ is a prime, not the completely general one.  Ignore me.

Comment: @Randall it's alright, it might not work in this case but at least I learned a new concept